# Nexus: Best way to "delete" a potentially dangerous version of an artifact

Tags: java, maven

Consider the following scenario: An artifact is published as "release" to the company Maven repository. After some time it is noticed that using this artifact (in production) is dangerous, i.e. it may destroy data of a data base, send wild e-mails to customers or something similar. What is the best (Maven) way to deal with this?

Up to now, the applied strategy is to delete the artifact from Nexus and from the local repository of the build server (and, of course, telling everyone what happened). This strategy has some disadvantages: Firstly, the developer can still use the artifact for his local build. Secondly, it is generally bad for reproducing bugs/situations to delete artifacts from the repository.

We think about implementing a "block list plugin" into the Maven build lifecycle that reads a company-global block list and breaks the build if one of the blocked artifacts appears. But we are open for any other "Best Practise" to solve this problem.

Comment: Another option is to use the Enforcer Plugin (if you have a company-wide parent POM) and ban that dependency completely, so that the build fails if anyone tries to use it.

Comment: If this artifacts has been deleted from your repository and developer can use it on it's own machine...but your CI server will show that there is something wrong...which is the foundation for deployments...

Comment: To use @Tunaki's idea, all projects would need to update to the version of the company-wide parent including the Enforcer plugin. This may or may not be a feasible solution depending on the number of projects in the enterprise.

Comment: Maven has the concept of a relocation POM, allowing a request for a POM with one set of coordinates to "point" at another artifact that should be used instead. We haven't had reason to use this but it might fit your use case.

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not quite get what you want to tell me.

Comment: @user944849 How does this "relocation" work? Do you have any source?

Comment: Found this doc link: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html. There's a section on how to move to a different groupId, but it looks like artifactId and version are also possibilities per this: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html#class_relocation. Looks like you may also add a message explaining the reason for the move.

Comment: If you delete an artifact from the repository. A developer can put as a dependency in a pom file. But that will be build later by CI solution which does not contain this dependency. So in the end the build process on CI will fail and will show there is something wrong...And only from a CI solution you should do deployments or never do deployments from a developers machine...

Comment: Exactly. This is why we do it. But still feels a bit odd. Maybe we also need an "evil" repository for these artifacts so that I can be used to reproduce old builds and test for bugs. This evil repository will of course be disconnected from the CI system.